# Attaching a View.OnKeyListener to a SurfaceView

Tags: android, listener, surfaceview

I need to attach custom touch and hardware key handling to a `SurfaceView`. I need to use separate listeners (rather than adding the `dispatchKeyEvent()` and `dispatchTouchEvent()` methods to the `SurfaceView`), as I will be providing the custom event handling functionality to a third party to use on their `SurfaceView`, and I want to keep it separate.

My custom *touch* event handler works fine, but the *key* event handler doesn't catch any events. Here's how I'm setting them:

```
public MyGLSurfaceView(Context c, AttributeSet a) {
    // Other setup...
    setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener()); // Works
    setOnKeyListener(new MyKeyListener()); // No events captured

}
```

And here's my key listener:

```
public class MyKeyListener implements View.OnKeyListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int key, KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("A hardware key was pressed!");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Should I be attaching the key listener to a different object than the `SurfaceView`? The view sits inside a `Dialog`, so could I attach my key listener to that instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the SurfaceView is not focusable and then doesn't broadcast keyevent.
You need to activate focus :

```
setFocusable(true);
setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
requestFocus();
//And now you set your OnKeyEventListener
```

Be aware that by loosing the focus for another view, this one will not receive any events until it receives the focus again.