# Issue with setOnKeyListener using crosswalk

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

I'm trying to start using crosswalk in a cordova app, the problem is that the app uses a custom plugin for a barcode reader in a specific device.

We basically have a plugin class that calls custom View which extends `EditText`, in the view we create a `OnKeyListener` to check if the specific key is press.

During the initialization of the plugin class we use the `webView.getView().setOnKeyListener(view.getScanKeyListener());` to create the `OnKeyListener` to check the keypress.

```
public class ScannerInputPlugin extends CordovaPlugin implements ScannerInputView.ScannerInputListener {
    private static CallbackContext callback = null;

    @Override
    public void pluginInitialize() {
        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new java.lang.Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ScannerInputView view = new ScannerInputView(cordova.getActivity(), ScannerInputPlugin.this);
                ((ViewGroup) webView.getView()).addView(view);
                webView.getView().setOnKeyListener(view.getScanKeyListener());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals("register")) {
            callback = callbackContext;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScannerInput(CharSequence input) {
        if (callback != null) {
            PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, input != null ? input.toString() : null);
            result.setKeepCallback(true);
            callback.sendPluginResult(result);
        }
    }
}
```

However in the view the `OnKeyListener` is never called, this only happens when using crosswalk, the only major change I found when debugging the app is that the `webview.engine` changes to a `XWalkWebViewEngine`.

```
public class ScannerInputView extends EditText {
    public static interface ScannerInputListener {
        void onScannerInput(CharSequence input);
    }

    public static final int KEYCODE_SCAN = 220;

    public ScannerInputView(Context context, final ScannerInputListener listener) {
        super(context);
        setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, 0));
        setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    if (count > 0 && s.charAt(start) != 0)
                        s = s.subSequence(start, start + count);
                    else
                        s = null;
                    listener.onScannerInput(s);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }

    public View.OnKeyListener getScanKeyListener() {
        return new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KEYCODE_SCAN && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    requestFocus();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I think this has something to do with the crosswalk engine but I have yet to find the cause, does anyone have any tips about the matter?

Answer (score 0):

As an update, I did manage to fix the issue by flowing the [stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381598/attaching-a-view-onkeylistener-to-a-surfaceview), I did not know about the XWalkView not being focusable by default, for future reference the solution for the issue was to setFocusable(true), setFocusableInTouchMode(true) and requestFocus() before the setOnKeyListener.

```
public void pluginInitialize() {
    cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new java.lang.Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ScannerInputView view = new ScannerInputView(cordova.getActivity(), ScannerInputPlugin.this);
            ((ViewGroup) webView.getView()).addView(view);
            webView.getView().setFocusable(true);
            webView.getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            webView.getView().requestFocus();
            webView.getView().setOnKeyListener(view.getScanKeyListener());
        }
    });
}
```